# How to find out the coordinates of the two vertices of a TopoDS_Edge (Openscascade)?

Tags: c++, opencascade

I want to find out the coordinates of the two vertices of a TopoDS_Edge.
I couldn't find any solution on the Public Member Functions list on https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_topo_d_s___edge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you can get the vertices of any topological object in OpenCascade:

```
TopoDS_Edge edge;
for (TopExp_Explorer ex(edge, TopAbs_VERTEX); ex.More(); ex.Next())
{
    gp_Pnt point = BRep_Tool::Pnt(TopoDS::Vertex(ex.Current()));
    double xCoord = point.X(); 
}
```

This is also capable of iterating over other types of topological entities like edges in a body when you replace TopAbs_VERTEX with TopAbs_EDGE.